# << no operator found and a unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I still very new to c++ so I probably did something weird. I'm writing a program that prints xmas trees to the screen. I've been able to do just using a string now I want to store parts of it in a variable and call each part as i need it. I keep on getting a c2679 error and a c4129 warning.

Okay now my questions:

Do I have to worry about the warnings since they do not need to be escaped?

How do I fix the c2679 error?

```
#include <iostream><string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is tree number "<< 1 <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t   *\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n\t\t\t\t *****\n\t\t\t\t\*******\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n";


    string aa,a,b,c,d;
    aa = "This is tree # ";
    a = "\t\t\t\t   *";
    b = "\n\t\t\t\t  ***";
    c = "\n\t\t\t\t *****";
    d = "\n\t\t\t\t\*******";

    cout << aa;
    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `\*` is that a typo !?

Comment: When you're trying to figure out why a program won't compile, look for the line number where the error occurred. It should be shown in the compiler output. (Then to match that number with a line in the program, you can turn on line numbers in the editor--instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx) for Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a `\` before the `*`.
Remove the `\`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is tree number "<< 1 <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t   *\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n\t\t\t\t *****\n\t\t\t\t*******\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n\t\t\t\t  ***\n";


    string aa,a,b,c,d;
    aa = "This is tree # ";
    a = "\t\t\t\t   *";
    b = "\n\t\t\t\t  ***";
    c = "\n\t\t\t\t *****";
    d = "\n\t\t\t\t*******";

    cout << aa;
    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

`\` denotes the start of an escape sequence. The characters you have after a `\` are `t`, `n`, `\` etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Also change

```
#include <iostream><string>
```

to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Comment: Thank You I would have never seen that